# Should I use an async wrapper when calling the Hangfire BackgroundJob.Enqueue method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hangfire

Is it a good idea to put the Enqueue method in an async wrapper and have the controller call it that way?

Which is better and why?

**Synchronously:**

```
    public IActionResult AddLogs(List<Log> logs)
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DM.AddLogsBackground(logs));
        return Ok();
    }
```

**Async:**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddLogs(List<Log> logs)
    {
        await DM.AddLogs(logs);
        return Ok();
    }

    public async Task AddLogs(List<Log> logs)
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => AddLogsBackground(logs));
    }
```

The [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-in-background.html) says:

> The Enqueue method does not call the target method immediately, it
>   runs the following steps instead:
>
> 1. Serialize a method information and all its arguments.
> 2. Create a new background job based on the serialized information.
> 3. Save background job to a persistent storage.
> 4. Enqueue background job to its queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which is better and why?

As `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` is not awaited (nor awaitable) it will just be processed synchronously.

So all the async syntax is useless and misleading here.

Note that your `DM.AddLogsBackground` [can be an async method](https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html#async-methods-for-background-jobs). But as far as I know, the processing will still be synchronous on the background job server.